# store images of different dimension in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have two images , image 1 of dimension (32,43,3) and image2 of dimension (67,86,3) . How can i store this in a numpy array , Whenever i try to append the array

```
image=cv2.imread(image1,0)
image=cv2.resize(image,(32,43))
x_train=np.array(image.flatten())
x_train=x_train.reshape(-1,3,32,43)
X_train =np.append(X_train,x_train) #X_train is my array

image=cv2.imread(image2,0)
image=cv2.resize(image,(67,86))
x_train=np.array(image.flatten())
x_train=x_train.reshape(-1,3,67,86)
X_train =np.append(X_train,x_train) 

Value Error: total size of new array must be unchanged.
```

i want the X_train in shape (-1,depth,height,width).So that i can feed it into my neural network. Is there any way to store images of different dimension in array and feed into neural network ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `np.append`.  If you must join arrays, start with `np.concatenate`.  It'll force you to pay more attention to the compatibility of dimensions.

You can't join 2 arrays with shapes (32,43,3) (67,86,3) to make a larger array of some compatible shape.  The only dimension they share is the last.

These reshapes don't make sense either: (-1,3,32,43), (-1,3,67,86).

It works, but it also messes up the 'image'. You aren't just adding a 4th dimension.  It looks like you want to do some axis swapping or transpose as well.  Practice with some small arrays so you can see what's happening, e.g. (2,4,3).

What final shape do you expect for `Xtrain`?

You can put these two images in a object dtype array, which is basically the same as the list `[image1, image2]`.  But I doubt if your neuralnet can do anything practical with that.

---

If you reshaped the (32,43,3) array to (16,86,3) you could concatenate that with (67,86,3) on axis=0 to produce a (83,86,3) array.  If you needed the `3` to be first, I'd use `np.transpose(..., (2,0,1))`.

Conversely reshape (67,86,3) to (2*67,43,3).

Passing the (32,43,3) to (32,86,3) is another option.

Joining them on a new 4th dimension, requires that the number of 'rows' match as well as the number of 'columns'.

Comment: Sir, I have dataset of images which are of different dimensions ,So i want to know if i can store all the dimensions in the same array , like [[3,67,83],[3,45,67],[3,63,67],........] and then i have to feed this array to my neural network. 
Final shape of Xtrain I expect is [3,None,None] as i dont want to fix the width and height of images while storing them .

Comment: We'd have to know more about your neural network.  The ones I've seen expect nice rectangular gridded in inputs, not a ragged mix of image sizes.  So far you have a list of images of different sizes, not an array.

Comment: I'm using [Spatial Pyramid Pooling](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4729), which allows CNN to take multi size inputs . Is there anyways besides cropping or padding the image , to feed multi size input in neural network ? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea of what shape of `(3, None, None)` means; at least not in `numpy`.  Are you using Theano or Tensorflow with Keras?

Comment: i'm using tenserflow with keras.

Comment: @Sarthak Gupta, can you please give your emailid, i have some doubt regarding SPP Net

Comment: sarthakg555@gmail.com