# ndarray object to array conversion, where object contains variable size images

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

I want to import images of different sizes in an array in format `(Number of images, row_size, col_size)`. I am using following code to do this.

```
import os,cv2, numpy as np
PATH = os.getcwd()
data_path = PATH+'/data'
data_dir_list = os.listdir(data_path)
img_data_list=[]
for dataset in data_dir_list:
    img_list=os.listdir(data_path+'/'+ dataset)
    print ('Loaded the images of dataset-'+'{}\n'.format(dataset))
    for img in img_list:
        input_img=cv2.imread(data_path + '/'+ dataset + '/'+ img,0)
        img_data_list.append(input_img)
img_data = np.array(img_data_list)
```

When i work with same size images i got proper result in `img_data` like example `size=(1000,50,50)` and `type=uint8` but when i work with different size images (all 1000 images are of different sizes like 34*45, 25*43........) i got of `img_data` like `size=(1000,)` `type=object` `value=ndarray object of numpy module` . I am working on deep learning in keras and python.

Comment: Will you not resize the image to give input to your CNN network?

Comment: From numpy reference: "An array object represents a multidimensional, **homogeneous** array of fixed-size items."

Comment: @Akhilesh yes i have experimented cnn many times with fixed size images. But now i want to do this variable size images to see the performance.

Comment: @Hitesh, Are you using dense layer(s) in your network?

Comment: @fferri ok, then please suggest other ways to import different size images.

Comment: you can use a python list of numpy arrays

Comment: @Akhilesh yes. model.add(Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax'))

Comment: @fferri how, please help in code

Comment: Did you try to give single image which is of different size that you gave in training. Because, as per my knowledge, you can give any image size in convolution layers, but the dense layers expects the same size of input that is provided at training time.

Comment: Yes, I know. I want to train my network with different sizes. What do you mean by single `image which is of different size that you gave in training`

Comment: I mean, if you are giving images with size of (50 x 50) for your CNN training, then just try other to give image of different size other than (50 x 50). You can will get error.

Comment: @Akhilesh i have experiment with same size images with both training and testing. Now i want to trian my network with different size images and also test with different size images.

Comment: @Hitesh, you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751952/store-images-of-different-dimension-in-numpy-array